# Change Date format from 2018-09-27T18:30:00.000Z to 2018-09-27 13:17:14

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

When I select a date using angular md-datepicker I receive date in 2018-09-27T18:30:00.000Z this format but in my database i have dates in 2018-09-27 13:17:14 this format, how can I convert dates in PHP to search in the database please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First create DateTime object then change to format whatever you want.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2018-09-27T18:30:00.000Z');
$databaseFormat = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```